# appium how to type into textField automatically

Tags: javascript, appium, nativescript

hello i'm working on ui-test  nativescript, with the appium plugin, I would like to know how to insert text in a field, I notify that I have already tried

`type("hello");`
`sendKeys("Text");`
`setValue("text");`
`getKeyboard().sendKeys("Text");`
`setText("text")`;

they return to me all, example for type("hello");

> type is not a function

i added [a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwPdw.png) for more details !

what is the good function to use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you are using [nativescript-
dev-appium](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-dev-appium), that is a wrapper over [wd](https://github.com/admc/wd) (node.js client for webdriver/appium)

This should work:

```
const element = await mascotteValue.element()
await element.sendKeys("text")
```

The error you face basically means there is not such function for `ui-element` object and you can see all the available ones [here](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-dev-appium/blob/master/lib/ui-element.d.ts).